# Xbox Live sign-in running Unity to authenticate Azure App Services / Mobile services

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, azure-mobile-services, xbox-live

I've got the [Unity Xbox Live services](https://github.com/Microsoft/xbox-live-unity-plugin) example up and running allowing me to sign-in to my Microsoft Account via Xbox Live services in Unity.

I've also got Azure App Services (Mobile services) running in Unity to query and persist my data. [App Services supports authentication out of the box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview) including Microsoft Account support.

Does anyone know if I can use the authentication from Xbox Live services sign-in to authentication my web calls against my Microsoft Account in App Services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets complicated :) although I can understand the frustration. Let me give a quick overview, but I'm happy to give more details as needed.

When dealing with sign-in, the first step is authentication - and there are three choices on such systems with Microsoft
1. MSA, or Microsoft Account, which is what most consumer systems use, such as Xbox.
2. AAD, or Azure Active Directory, which is typically for enterprise applications.
3. S2S, or Server to Server, which is typically done either with an SSL certificate or shared secret. (Note this is also similar to the app secret mentioned above, although app secret is less secure since the secret is with the app itself, but this and MSA do go together).

These three systems are very different in goals, designs and requirements so there isn't really an option to unify them.

Now lets assume that you are using only #1 above - signing in with MSA. You might wonder why you can't take the token returned for one set of services and use it with another. Now we are into the realm of user privacy and security isolation. Have you noticed when you sign into a game on the PC with XboxLive that you get a dialog box asking if it is okay? That is the consent dialog and is required so that malicious apps can't steal a token for one part of a system (say your outlook.com sign-in) and use it to grab data from elsewhere (onedrive, xbox, etc) without the user saying "yes, that is okay". This same thing happens with systems like Facebook, etc - it is a fairly standard system.

So, to enable this, each time you ask MSA for a token, you have to specify the site you are going to use it with, so MSA knows what consent to ask for - and to ensure it stays only to that site.

tl;dr - doing security right means more hassles :) But the good news is that the underlying system should be able to detect these and prevent the user from having to present a sign-in for each site - just one sign-in, but possibly multiple consent dialogs. And more code for the developer...

Comment: Another quick note - the OS actually has a lot of code to handle some of these scenarios since you can sign into Windows with your MSA - that authentication is the basis for access a lot of different parts, like the store, xbox, etc. The Azure app secret is a separate library that uses the same MSA service, but leverages app identity via Azure (which Windows doesn't need). There are definitely places where we could do a better job unifying some of these systems.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know if I can use the authentication from Xbox Live services sign-in to authentication my web calls against my Microsoft Account in App Services?

AFAIK, for app service authentication with Microsoft Account, you need to create the application in [Microsoft Account Developer Center](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com), then you need to add **Client Id** and **Client Secret** for your Microsoft Account provider under "Settings > Authentication / Authorization" of your App Service application. For more details, you could refer to [Microsoft Account authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-microsoft-authentication).

Based on your scenario, you could only use the [Client-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#clientflow) for Microsoft Account. Additionally, the app service authentication for Microsoft Account uses [LiveSDK](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK) for [initiating the sign-in process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659750.aspx). Though, I'm not familiar with Xbox Live services sign-in, based on my understanding, I assumed that you could not achieve this purpose for now.

Comment: Thanks, that's a shame. Feels like they use the same tech under the hood and should be able to hook them together. I will leave this open to see if anyone from the Xbox team knows more.